# unity 3d: how to collect and drop 5 spawned object one after the other on a slot

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

**Am having problem with my unity c# code, object spawn at a position , and 
how to pick and drop object spawned on each slot using the slot number and the fill counter** so that i can be able to pick seeds from the slot and drop it one by one on other slots and count the current seeds on the slots
 And also making  it a turned based game with  timer

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class slotProperty : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public bool isFilled = false;
    [SerializeField] private int fillCounter;
    public SlotManager slotManager;
    public Transform spawnLocation;
    [SerializeField] private int slotNum;
    // public GameObject slots;

    private void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
        {
            if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "slot_1")
            if (!isFilled)
                //To spawn 5 seeds on slot 1 - 7

                if (slotNum <= 7) 
                { 
                    {
                        Instantiate(slotManager.fillAvailableBall(), spawnLocation.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        fillCounter++;
                        if (fillCounter == 5)
                            isFilled = true;
                    }
                }
                //To spawn 5 seeds on slot 8 and 9

                else if (slotNum <= 9)   
                {
                    {
                        Instantiate(slotManager.fillAvailableBall(), spawnLocation.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        fillCounter++;
                        if (fillCounter == 1)
                            isFilled = true;
                    }
                }

                //To spawn 5 seeds on slot 10
                else if (slotNum == 10)
                {
                    {
                        Instantiate(slotManager.fillAvailableBall(), spawnLocation.transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
                        fillCounter++;
                        if (fillCounter == 5)
                            isFilled = true;
                    }
                }
                else if(slotNum <= 20)
                {
                    {
                        fillCounter++;
                        if (fillCounter == 0)
                            isFilled = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to understand why you are using `{ }` enclosed blocks within each and every `if - else` block ... but not where some would actually be helpful: after `if (!isFilled)`

Comment: If (! IsFilled)  is checking  the number object to be spawned on the slot